# vcxsrv: reset display settings after saving configuration

Tags: configuration, xserver, xlaunch

I am using vcxsrv to run graphical applications on a linux-cluster. However when I started using it and was asked to select a display setting, I selected one large window and saved this configuration. Now I found that one large window is quite impractical in many cases and would like to change it to multiple windows but don't know how. I am not shown the dialogue-box for choosing the display settings anymore when launching the application and I was looking for some config.xlaunch file that I read about in another post but couldn't find any. I am also not sure where this file would be saved. maybe I was just searching in the wrong place.

Does anybody know how to reset the display settings or where the config file is usually saved?

Answer (score 1):

Simply execute "vcxsrv.exe" from your VcXsrv install directory.